# Find the border patch where randomly moved particle hit

Tags: netlogo

I have a randomly blue drawn border and a ball which is placed inside border and should randomly move inside, when it hits a wall it should turn in opposite direction and continue. For that I`ve wrote a code

```
breed [ balls ball ]
ask balls
  [
    ifelse (pcolor = blue or [pcolor] of patch-at dx dy = blue)
    [  
     rt 180
    ]
    [
      jump 0.4
    ]
  ]
```

This code seems to work, but now there is a need to create a flash when the ball hits a wall. I`ve tried the following code - with no success

```
breed [ flashes flash ]
flashes-own [ birthday ]

to apply-flash-visualization
  set size 2.5
  if (ticks - birthday > 0.4)  [ die ]
end

to go
  ask flashes [ apply-flash-visualization ]
  ask balls
  [
    ifelse (pcolor = blue or [pcolor] of patch-at dx dy = blue)
    [  
     rt 180
      if (pcolor = blue)
      [
        let bounce-patch patch-here
        let new-px [ pxcor ] of bounce-patch
        let new-py [ pycor ] of bounce-patch
        ask patch new-px new-py [
          sprout 1 [
            set breed flashes
            set color gray - 2
            set birthday ticks
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [
      jump 0.4
    ]
  ]
```

How should the issue be solved?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the `if (pcolor = blue)` line that's causing the problem. Your `ball` agents are never actually on a blue patch, since you have them turn around once they assess the patch ahead of them (using your `patch-at dx dy` line). So, `if (pcolor = blue)` never evaluates to true, so no flashes are ever made. This would be a good place for a print command for debugging- if you put something like:

```
...
     if (pcolor = blue)
      [
        print "making flash"
...
```

you'll see that that code is never actually evaluated. So to fix this, you have to re-evaluate when the flashes should actually occur- one simple example that might work for you:

```
breed [ flashes flash ]
breed [ balls ball ]

flashes-own [ birthday ]

to setup
  ca
  ask patches with [ 
    member? pxcor list max-pxcor min-pxcor or
    member? pycor list max-pycor min-pycor 
  ] [
    set pcolor blue
  ]

  create-balls 10 

  reset-ticks
end

to apply-flash-visualization
  set size size + 1
  if ticks - birthday > 2  [ die ]
end


to go
  ask flashes [ apply-flash-visualization ]
  ask balls [
    let next patch-ahead 1
    ifelse [pcolor] of next = blue [
      ask next [
        sprout-flashes 1 [
          set shape "square"
          set color white
          set birthday ticks
        ]
      ]
      rt 180
    ] [
      fd 1
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Also, you may want to look at the "Bounce Example" model in the Models Library that shows how to make angled bouncing work.